# How many sentence types are there in English?

Tags: grammar, sentence

As the header says - how many distinct sentence types are there in the English language?

Comment: As in declarative, interrogative, etc.? And do you already know the answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are precisely fourteen.

1. Sentences that belong to the emperor
2. Embalmed sentences
3. Sentences that are trained
4. Sentences regarding suckling pigs
5. Sentences regarding mermaids (or sirens)
6. Fabulous sentences
7. Sentences involving stray dogs
8. Sentences that are included in this classification
9. Sentences that tremble as if they were mad
10. Innumerable ones
11. Those drawn with a very fine camel hair brush
12. Et cetera
13. Sentences that have just broken the flower vase
14. Sentences that, at a distance, resemble flies

See also [Celestial Emporium of Benevolent Knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_Emporium_of_Benevolent_Knowledge).

Comment: This list has stirred considerable philosophical and literary commentary. Lol! Wonderful answer!

Comment: @Susan, as per the link, Jorge Luis Borges beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

Types of Sentences by Structure - 4: Simple, Compound Sentence, Complex, and Complex-Compound.
Types of Sentences by Purpose - 5: Declarative, Interrogative, Exclamatory, Imperative, and Conditional (x 5: present general, future more-vivid, future less-vivid, present contrafactual, and past contrafactual).

Therefore 4x4x5 = 80.

Or, 1. A [sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_%28linguistics%29) can also be defined in orthographic terms alone, i.e., as **anything which is contained between a capital letter and a full stop.**

For instance, the opening of Charles Dickens' novel Bleak House begins with the following three **sentences**:

> London. Michaelmas term lately over, and the Lord Chancellor sitting in Lincoln's Inn Hall. Implacable November weather.

There is no one correct answer. It depends on whose definition you are using.

Comment: Then there are SVOd, OdSV...; SVOiOd...; complements; obligatory directionals; extra-grammatical idioms.... Dare one even mention parentheticals?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - exactly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I'd say these are sentence structures, rather than sentence types. I guess it depends on what your point of view is.

Comment: @Susan - what's the difference between a conditional and a declarative sentence? I know the mood of the verb is different, but can that be said to change the sentence type? 'If I had flour I could bake bread', to me, is as much a declarative sentence as 'I can bake bread'. The classical definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhema#Greek_philosophers) would be a grammatical structure with noun (onoma), and verb (rhema) which combined to form a meaningful structure (logos), and I see this as implied in the Dickens example ('The place is London', for instance - or even 'The setting: London').

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that it depends on who is doing the defining. [This](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/Declarative-Question-term.htm) has been deemed a declarative question.